# How do I upload an image file in slim 3?

Tags: php, android, html, slim

**I have to upload an image file on a server using slim 3. I want to save the file path in table and respective image in folder on server**

```
 $filenamePath = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpg";
        $decoded=base64_decode($image);
        file_put_contents("images/".$filenamePath,$decoded);

        $sth = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE orders set status =:status,
                                      total_amount=:amount,created_at=:date1,receipt=:path WHERE id=:orderId");
        $sth->bindParam("orderId",$orderid );
        $sth->bindParam("status", $status);
        $sth->bindParam("amount", $amount);
        $sth->bindParam("date1", $date);
        $sth->bindParam("path", $filenamePath);
        $sth->execute();
```

> This is my code in slim 3 class
>   [this is my directory stucture of folder on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vzVd.png)
>   *What is wrong? Can anyone help?*

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: `i have to upload image file on server using slim 3`. Well what goes wrong? And what does it have to do with Android?

Comment: failed to open stream no such file or directory ..this error is there

Comment: ??? Where is that error? And you did not tell what it has to do with Android.

Comment: https://akrabat.com/psr-7-file-uploads-in-slim-3/

Comment: @Mika Tuupola, thanks it is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filenamePath = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpg";
    $decoded=base64_decode($image);
    file_put_contents("../images/".$filenamePath,$decoded);

    $sth = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE orders set status =:status,
                                  total_amount=:amount,created_at=:date1,receipt=:path WHERE id=:orderId");
    $sth->bindParam("orderId",$orderid );
    $sth->bindParam("status", $status);
    $sth->bindParam("amount", $amount);
    $sth->bindParam("date1", $date);
    $sth->bindParam("path", $filenamePath);
    $sth->execute();
```

***just change path as in above code and given permission for images folder***

Answer (score 1):

**Try full path of your image**

**Example:**

```
file_put_contents("/testslim/v1/src/images/".$filenamePath,$decoded);
```